# Powershell, how to add permission to shared folder

Tags: powershell

I have the following code which creates a shared folder

```
if (!(Test-Path c:\myFolder))
{
    New-Item -Path 'c:\myFolder' -ItemType Directory
}

If (!(GET-WMIOBJECT Win32_Share -Filter "Name='myFolder'”))
{ 
    $Shares.Create(“c:\myFolder”,”myFolder”,0)
}
```

How can i add Read/Write permission to 'Everyone' to the shared folder?
I prefer not to add external dll

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Carbon](http://get-carbon.org) module has an [Install-Share](http://get-carbon.org/help/Install-Share.html) function that will do what you need:

```
 Install-Share -Name myFolder -Path C:\myFolder -Permissions "EVERYONE,FULL"
```

Internally, `Install-Share` is using the `net share` console application.  I believe if you run `net share /?`, you'll get syntax on how to create a share from the command line.

***Disclaimer:*** I am the owner/maintainer of Carbon.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `Set-SharePermission` function from the ShareUtils module (http://en-us.sysadmins.lv/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=28):

```
Import-Module ShareUtils

Get-Share -Name myFolder | 
Set-SharePermission -User Everyone -AccessType Allow -Permission Change | 
Set-Share
```

Comment: i get: "Get-Share : The term 'Get-Share' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again." Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but it's much more complicated. You can take a look at the code of the functions to get the picture.

Comment: can you share an example without your module?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any examples, I use the module (its not mine).

Comment: Try here: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Create-a-Share-and-Set-eb177a79